# Is this use of Obj.magic necessary?

Tags: ocaml

I am reading a repository and I encountered this function in the body of some Yojson json parsing code:

```
let load_problems channel =
  let open Yojson.Basic.Util in
  let j = Yojson.Basic.from_channel channel in
  ...
  let rec unpack x =
    try magical (x |> to_int) with _ ->
    try magical (x |> to_float) with _ ->
    try magical (x |> to_bool) with _ ->
    try
      let v = x |> to_string in
      if String.length v = 1 then magical v.[0] else magical v
    with _ ->
    try
      x |> to_list |> List.map ~f:unpack |> magical
    with _ -> raise (Failure "could not unpack")
  in
  ...
```

where `magical = Obj.magic`.  I understand what Obj.magic is (it's the equivalent to `Unsafe.Coerce` in Haskell), but I don't see why a type coercion is necessary here.  The `Yojson.Basic.Util` functions the author uses should already either succeed or fail to do this conversion.  Any intuition?

EDIT:

I feel I was depriving @glennsl of context, so here is the immediately following passage in which `unpack` is used:

```
  let tf = j |> member "tasks" |> to_list |> List.map ~f:(fun j -> 
      let e = j |> member "examples" |> to_list in
      let task_type = j |> member "request" |> deserialize_type in 
      let examples = e |> List.map ~f:(fun ex -> (ex |> member "inputs" |> to_list |> List.map ~f:unpack,
                                                  ex |> member "output" |> unpack)) in
      let maximum_frontier = j |> member "maximumFrontier" |> to_int in
      let name = j |> member "name" |> to_string in

      let task =
        (try
           let special = j |> member "specialTask" |> to_string in
           match special |> Hashtbl.find task_handler with
           | Some(handler) -> handler (j |> member "extras")
           | None -> (Printf.eprintf " (ocaml) FATAL: Could not find handler for %s\n" special;
                      exit 1)
         with _ -> supervised_task) ~timeout:timeout name task_type examples
      in 
      (task, maximum_frontier))
  in
```

There are a number of different `task_handler`s, but the one I happen to be concerned with is defined as follows:

```
(fun extras ?timeout:(timeout = 0.001) name ty examples ->
    let open Yojson.Basic.Util in

    let cost_matters =
      try
        extras |> member "costMatters" |> to_bool
      with _ -> assert false
    in 

    let by = match examples with
      | [([0],y)] ->
        Bigarray.(Array1.of_array int8_unsigned c_layout (Array.of_list y))
      | [([1],y)] ->
        Bigarray.(Array1.of_array int8_unsigned c_layout (Array.of_list y))
      | _ -> failwith "not a turtle task" in
    { name = name    ;
      task_type = ty ;
      log_likelihood =
        (fun p ->
           try
             match run_recent_logo ~timeout p with
             | Some(bx,cost) when (LogoLib.LogoInterpreter.fp_equal bx by 0) ->
               (if cost_matters then (0.-.cost)*.10. else 0.)
             | _ -> log 0.
           with (* We have to be a bit careful with exceptions if the
                 * synthesized program generated an exception, then we just
                 * terminate w/ false but if the enumeration timeout was
                 * triggered during program evaluation, we need to pass the
                 * exception on
                *)
           | UnknownPrimitive(n) -> raise (Failure ("Unknown primitive: "^n))
           | EnumerationTimeout  -> raise EnumerationTimeout
           | _                   -> log 0.0)
    });;
```

The author also uses `;;` in a lot of files..another quirk.

Comment: > Any intuition?
That code is horribly wrong, avoid at all cost.

Comment: There's really not enough context here to tell. It _is_ necessary in the sense that there's no other way to cram a bunch of heterogeneous values into an ordinary list of an amorphous unknown type, but why on earth you'd do that is beyond me. I'd suggest killing the code with fire and banning the author from ever touching a computer again.

Comment: yeah..it's a researcher's repository--big shock.  The context is simply that they wanted a Python "frontend"/Python access to pytorch, so they have to launch/communicate with OCaml processes via JSON.  This function is always applied to homogeneous inputs as far as I can tell.  This is simply the function they wrote for parsing the only list field they pass.

Comment: @glennsl can you actually make a hetlist this way?  How will the ultimate type unify?  Does Obj.magic actually allow you to work with a list of objects of completely ungrounded type?

Comment: `Obj.magic` completely circumvents the type system. It will unify with anything on either end. That's mostly what makes this so bad, that there's no restriction of any kind. You can certainly _create_ a hetlist this way, that's effectively what this does. Getting the data out again is the problem though, since there's no runtime type information.

Comment: I assume this is used like `let numbers : int list = unpack something` and just hoping the JSON only contains ints? If so this could be made much simpler and without any use of `Obj.magic` just by passing in the appropriate `Util` function. E.g. `unpack to_int something`, with the type of `unpack` being `val unpack : (json -> 'a) -> json -> 'a list`.

Comment: That would be a sane assumption